# Github Actions: Is it Possible to Reference a Variable within a Context?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I would like to be able to reference a github secret based on a project directories name variable so that I only need 1 workflow to handle many projects.

```
  - name: Build Subject Key Secret String
    run: |
     secret_prefix='WASH_'
     secret_unique=$(echo $ACTOR_NAME | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z')
     secret_suffix='_KEY'
     secret=${secret_prefix}${secret_unique}${secret_suffix}
     echo "SECRET_STRING=$secret" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  - name: Pull Subject Key Secret
    run: |
     echo "WASH_SUBJECT_SECRET=${{ secrets.env.SECRET_STRING }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

I Have tried many things to reference the variable within the context including: `secrets.SECRET_STRING`, `secrets.$SECRET_STRING`, `secrets.${SECRET_STRING}`, `env.SECRET_STRING` (`secrets.` was concatenated to front of prefix). I also tried to declare env secret in a subsequent step:

```
        env:
          WASH_SUBJECT_KEY: ${{ secrets.SECRET_STRING }}
```

I am not sure if it is possible to do something like this, or if there is a better way. If anyone has done something like this before, I would be grateful for some assistance. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try $GITHUB_ENV[$secret] ?

Comment: No I did not! I will! Thanks for suggestion @GrzegorzKrukowski! I don't think that will work though, because that variable was not exported from the previous step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could dynamically access to the secret name using square braces, like:

```
secrets[env.SECRET_STRING]
```

So you could do something like:

```
  - name: Pull Subject Key Secret
    run: |
     echo "WASH_SUBJECT_SECRET=${{ secrets[env.SECRET_STRING] }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Comment: You are my HERO. You may just want to edit the answer so that there is no space between the `env.` and `SECRET_STRING`. I misconstrued for a missing $. Thank you so so much.